# Frobenius norm and trace of matrix

Tags: trace

Given a real, symmetric and positive-definite matrix G.
G' = transposed matrix of G

Please, could you tell me which class of matrices that satisfy:
Frobenius norm of G = [trace(GG')]^1/2 = trace[(GG')^1/2]

Thanks

Comment: If $G$ is symmetric, then $G = G'$...

Comment: You should try to savage the answer to your last question. If you need a hint: rank $1$ matrices.